# How to categorize linux servers

Tags: linux, aws, cloud, google-cloud

**This is not the technical problem or issue but just a programming scenario which I am facing and need to work around this and try to solve this so need some hints on this scenario.**

Our team has to manage a huge number of other user's Linux machines on cloud(AWS). Every machine is either a Database server, Application Server or Web server. Is there any way to detect this programmatically.

**These users are not the part of our team or company. These are simply end users and we can only manage thier linux servers by taking control with their permission. So, problem is that how we detect about their machines.**

How we search in specific linux machines so that we will be able to identify that it is database server or application server for instance.

Is there any way through which we can identify the type of linux machine?

**For Example:**

- Some developers create some linux machines on cloud and install only
  mysql , oracle or some other related database softwares so that it
  becomes database linux server which handles only database operations.
- And, some developers create some linux machines where they will
  install apache or some other web-server related softwares so that it
  becomes web server and do only web-related tasks and they cann't handle 
  or accept any kind of database operations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk to your colleagues. Get them to classify their servers for you. Put it in a registry of some sort. Maybe even agree on a naming scheme? This is a social problem, not a technical one.

Comment: @Kusalananda actually our team handles those user's linux servers which are not our colleagues or team-mates. That's why we are unable to communicate with them. They are only our end users and take control of those linux servers with their permission. So, you have any idea to identify those servers.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have also edited the question. Please read and give some hints if you face this kind of scenario.

Comment: If they install mysql but do not run it, is it a database server? If they install mysql and apache but use mysql only with a web application, is it a database server or a web server or both? If they run Firefox browser, which uses sqlite, is it a database server?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, it's a database server if they install only database softwares and it's a web server if they install only apache and other web-related softwares.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan those nodes on opened ports with nmap. It should be reliable, if those services use standard application ports.

There is simple example of nmap usage:

```
nmap -sS -O server.mydomain
...
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
514/tcp  open  shell
2301/tcp open  compaqdiag
2381/tcp open  compaq-https
...
```

Google for more examples and ports used by your interesting services.

Comment: following error is thrown -bash: nmap: command not found

Comment: Then you have to install the nmap package to your system...

Comment: we are using end user's linux machine and we don't have install access on that machine, so we are working around without any installs so if you have any idea related to that then please share with me. Thanks.

Comment: Well, for such a type of scan nmap requires root permissions. With ordinary user permissions you may try to establish connection to your interesting service ports with telnet. You have to use known ports and try.

Comment: Have you any idea instead of nmap or telnet ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. If your company requires something from you, it must give you adequate tools...